# Oracle: Insufficient privileges on inserting data into tablespace tables

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

I'm a little new to all this... I want to create a new tablespace that will contain all my tables and indexes.

first the tablespace code..

```
create tablespace  Sales_T  
datafile      'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\project\dataexample.dbf'  
size 100m 
autoextend on next 100m;
```

and then the user that will be assigned on this space:

```
create user app_admin identified by "p4ss" default tablespace
sales_T temporary tablespace temp; 

grant connect, resource to app_admin; 

grant dba to app_admin;
```

Logging in to app_admin user, I can create tables but can't query or insert data into them, which privileges do I need to grant to?

Comment: your creation of tablespace and tables succeeds ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
grant imp_full_database to p4ss;
```

This will lets you access your database and let you query over it.

Answer (score 0):

The quota may be the problem:

```
sql>select username,tablespace_name,max_bytes from dba_ts_quotaS WHERE USERNAME='p4ss';

no rows selected
quotas are not allocate for p4ss user

sql> alter user p4ss quota unlimited on sales_T;

sql>select username,tablespace_name,max_bytes from dba_ts_quotaS WHERE USERNAME='p4ss';

USERNAME                       TABLESPACE_NAME                 MAX_BYTES
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
P4SS                           SALES_T                                 -1
```

-1 means unlimited

Comment: Please include an explanation of what your commands are supposed to do, and why you think they will help solve the problem.  I made a guess, but please edit the answer again if I misunderstood, or if you can make it clearer.